# Count instances of transactions per day pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to retrieve a column from a csv file and make it an index in a dataframe. However, I realize that I might need to do another step beforehand.

The csv looks like this;

```
Date,Step,Order,Price
    2011-01-10,Step,BUY,150
    2011-01-10,Step,SELL,150
    2011-01-13,Step,SELL,150
    2011-01-13,Step1,BUY,400
    2011-01-26,Step2,BUY,100
```

If I print the dataframe this is the output:

```
    Date Step Order  Price
0      0   Step  BUY    150
1      1   Step  SELL   150
2      2   Step  SELL   150
3      3   Step1 BUY    400
4      4   Step2 BUY    100
```

However, the output that I would like is to tell how many buys/sells per type of Step I have on each day.

For example;

The expected dataframe and output are:

```
Date        Num-Buy-Sell                                               
2011-01-10   2
2011-01-13   2
2011-01-16   1
```

This is the code on how I'm retrieving the data frame;

```
num_trasanctions_day = pd.read_csv(orders_file, parse_dates=True, sep=',', dayfirst=True)
num_trasanctions_day['Transactions'] = orders.groupby(['Date', 'Order'])
num_trasanctions_day['Date'] = num_trasanctions_day.index
```

My first thought was to make date the index, but I guess I need to calculate how many sell/buys are there per date.

**Error**

```
KeyError: 'Order'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `value_counts`

```
df.Date.value_counts()
Out[27]: 
    2011-01-13    2
    2011-01-10    2
    2011-01-26    1
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Edit: If you want to assign it back , you are looking for `transform` also, please modify your expected output.

```
df['Transactions']=df.groupby('Date')['Order'].transform('count')
df
Out[122]: 
             Date   Step Order  Price  Transactions
0      2011-01-10   Step   BUY    150             2
1      2011-01-10   Step  SELL    150             2
2      2011-01-13   Step  SELL    150             2
3      2011-01-13  Step1   BUY    400             2
4      2011-01-26  Step2   BUY    100             1
```

Comment: If I do num_trasanctions_day['Transactions'] = num_trasanctions_day.Date.value_counts() then it prints only NaN's . Is there a way to append those counts to a column as your output?

Comment: @Codinghierarchy add `.to_frame()`

Comment: Still NaNs 
num_trasanctions_day['Transactions'] = num_trasanctions_day.Date.value_counts().to_frame()

Comment: Thank you for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Codinghierarchy if it is work ..you can accept it ~ :-)